# How to get search button in ExtJs 4.1.1?

Tags: javascript, button, extjs4.1

If I use 'x-form-search trigger' as iconCls in a button, the search(magnifying glass) icon appears as an image inside of the button. How do I make the icon the button and not an image inside the button?

Or is there any other way to get the search icon as a button?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a clickable image and that you dont need the button component at all

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a button with search icon you can write a trigger click function and than on click of the search icon i.e a trigger of the combo you can write your logic or call a function
Below is the example

```
      // The data store containing the list of states
           var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    onTrigger1Click: function(event) {
                                   alert('WRITE YOUR LOGIC HERE');
                                },

});
```